# Choosing between additive and multiplicative Holt-Winters Model

Tags: r, smoothing, forecasting

While using the Holt-Winters model for seasonality, I am unable to choose a better fit between additive and multiplicative models. I used to look at RMSE value and choose the one with the lower RMSE. But in the following example, the multiplicative model has a higher RMSE but it is still a better fit. How to choose between multiplicative and additive model ?

```
library(fma)
library(ggplot2)
data(txhousing)
hstarts <- txhousing[,'hstarts'] 
hstartsHWa<-hw(hstarts,seasonal = "additive")
hstartsHWm<-hw(hstarts,seasonal = "multiplicative")
autoplot(hstarts) +
autolayer(hstartsHWa, series="HW additive forecasts",
        PI=FALSE) +
autolayer(hstartsHWm, series="HW multiplicative forecasts",
        PI=FALSE) +
ggtitle("Housing Starts") +
guides(colour=guide_legend(title="Forecast"))
```

The plot shows that the multiplicative model is better fit even though it has higher RMSE.

Comment: Um, do you have a question?

Comment: I don't see a real question here. Nevertheless: in my opinion your question is better asked at CrossValidated since Stack Overflow focusses on programming issues.

Comment: I have added a question. Please see if u can answer it.